# JS how to prompt user to enable notifications

Tags: javascript, notifications

Websites sometimes prompts the user to show notifications. How do I do this (with JS)?

[image: Picture]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just use the notifications API and this message is automatic then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Notification.requestPermission()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission):

> The `requestPermission()` method of the `Notification` interface requests permission from the user for the current origin to display notifications.

```
Notification.requestPermission()
  .then(function(permission) {
    // ...
  });
```